# Yii ajaxSubmitButton url issue

Tags: yii

I have a form with this code

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'user-contact-info-form',
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('user/editContactInfo'), //<- your form action here
            'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        ));
```

and and ajax submit button with this code:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save !!!','mysite/updateInfo',array(
   'type'=>'POST',
   'success'=>'js:function(data){
       alert(data);
       }
   }',
));
```

Instead of defining the url 'mysite/updateInfo' the jquery created is:

```
jQuery('body').undelegate('#yt0','click').delegate('#yt0','click',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'post','data':'_lang=en&YII_CSRF_TOKEN=83434e217ef914b4f6a3602a60cba77b803567c7','success':function(data) {window.location.reload();},'url':'/alice/index.php?r=user/update','cache':false});return false;});
```

This is not what I mean. Whats the hell I am doing wrong?

Comment: The generated jQuery you're showing appears to be for a different element than the submit button you're showing us code for . . . not sure which element has been assigned the id yt0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use either

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save !!!',Yii::app()->createUrl('mysite/updateInfo'),...
```

or

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save !!!',array('mysite/updateInfo'),...
```